# Updating an indicator from pinescript 2 to pine script 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am hoping to have some help updating TrendAlert by rstraat (readily available in Tradingview) to Pinescript 5. It is in version 2, and TV can do version 3 up to 5 but man, something changed with the Heiken Ashi candle portions of the script that I cant figure out. Here is the original code block

```
//@version=2
study("TrendAlert", overlay=false)

// Trend and direction determination Step 1 en Step 2 method conform ZoneRecovery from 4x-dat.com Joseph Nemeth 
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxDAYtlQjBM
// step 1 LongTerm timefram/resolution (LT) determine general direction 
//• color last Heikenahsi bar gives is the general direction 
// step 2 MidTerm timeframe/resolution determine trend
//• color last Heikenahsi bar must match Direction step 1 and
//• slope of 20EMA in direction step 1 and 
//• price relation to EMA20: above = up, below=down 
// Step 1 AND step 2 => TrendAlert (-1 for Short, 1 for Long, 0 for No trend)

//Heiken Ashi Candles
data = heikenashi(tickerid)
resLT = input(title="Res LT", type=resolution, defval="D")
resMT = input(title="Res MT", type=resolution, defval="240")


LTo = security(data, resLT, open)
LTc = security(data, resLT, close)
MTo = security(data, resMT, open)
MTc = security(data, resMT, close)

LTlong = LTc > LTo 
LTshort = LTc < LTo 
MTema20 = ema(MTc,20)
MTema20delta= change(MTema20)

MTlong = MTc > MTo and MTc > MTema20 and MTema20delta > 0
MTshort = MTc < MTo and MTc < MTema20 and MTema20delta < 0



Long = MTlong and LTlong
Short = MTshort and LTshort

plot(Long ? 1 : Short ? -1: 0, title="TrendAlert", color= Long ? lime : Short ? red : gray, style=columns )
```

and here is how far I have gotten.

```
//@version=5
indicator("TrendAlert", overlay=false)

// Trend and direction determination Step 1 en Step 2 method conform ZoneRecovery from 4x-dat.com Joseph Nemeth
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxDAYtlQjBM
// step 1 LongTerm timefram/resolution (LT) determine general direction
//• color last Heikenahsi bar gives is the general direction
// step 2 MidTerm timeframe/resolution determine trend
//• color last Heikenahsi bar must match Direction step 1 and
//• slope of 20EMA in direction step 1 and
//• price relation to EMA20: above = up, below=down
// Step 1 AND step 2 => TrendAlert (-1 for Short, 1 for Long, 0 for No trend)

//Heiken Ashi Candles
data = ta.heikenashi(tickerid)
resLT = input(title="Res LT", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
resMT = input(title="Res MT", type=input.resolution, defval="240")

LTo = security(syminfo.tickerid, resLT, open)
LTc = security(syminfo.tickerid, resLT, close)
MTo = security(syminfo.tickerid, resMT, open)
MTc = security(syminfo.tickerid, resMT, close)

LTlong = LTc > LTo
LTshort = LTc < LTo
MTema20 = ta.ema(MTc,20)
MTema20delta= ta.change(MTema20)

MTlong = MTc > MTo and MTc > MTema20 and MTema20delta > 0
MTshort = MTc < MTo and MTc < MTema20 and MTema20delta < 0

Long = MTlong and LTlong
Short = MTshort and LTshort

plotshape(Long ? 1 : Short ? -1: 0, title="TrendAlert", color= Long ? color.lime : Short ? color.red : color.gray, style=shape.columns )
```

I get the following errors:
Error at 15:22 Undeclared identifier 'tickerid'
Error at 15:8 Could not find function or function reference 'ta.heikenashi'

help
ps. If you load the script and see what it does, I would be interested in any other script that performs the same function. as long as it can be updated to v5

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not used in your script, just delete it.
There are other several things to change, here is the version 5 :

```
//@version=5
indicator("TrendAlert", overlay=false)

// Trend and direction determination Step 1 en Step 2 method conform ZoneRecovery from 4x-dat.com Joseph Nemeth
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxDAYtlQjBM
// step 1 LongTerm timefram/resolution (LT) determine general direction
//• color last Heikenahsi bar gives is the general direction
// step 2 MidTerm timeframe/resolution determine trend
//• color last Heikenahsi bar must match Direction step 1 and
//• slope of 20EMA in direction step 1 and
//• price relation to EMA20: above = up, below=down
// Step 1 AND step 2 => TrendAlert (-1 for Short, 1 for Long, 0 for No trend)

//Heiken Ashi Candles
//data = ta.heikenashi()
resLT = input.string(title="Res LT", defval="D")
resMT = input.string(title="Res MT", defval="240")

LTo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resLT, open)
LTc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resLT, close)
MTo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resMT, open)
MTc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resMT, close)

LTlong = LTc > LTo
LTshort = LTc < LTo
MTema20 = ta.ema(MTc,20)
MTema20delta= ta.change(MTema20)

MTlong = MTc > MTo and MTc > MTema20 and MTema20delta > 0
MTshort = MTc < MTo and MTc < MTema20 and MTema20delta < 0

Long = MTlong and LTlong
Short = MTshort and LTshort

plot(Long ? 1 : Short ? -1: 0, title="TrendAlert", color= Long ? color.lime : Short ? color.red : color.gray, style=plot.style_columns )
```

Comment: @Tice what are your results with this answer ?